# Linux kernel make ERROR : no rule to make target 'FORCE', needed by './config_data.gz' stop

Tags: c, linux, makefile, kernel

I'm editing the Linux kernel. But make doesnt work.

```
no rule to make target 'FORCE', needed by './config_data.gz' stop
```

This error keeps coming out. What's the solution?

[image]

Comment: Provide full information about how you acquired the kernel source code, what steps you took to configure the kernel, etc.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]" to learn how this site works. Then come back and [edit] your question, answering the questions we have. Mine is: What version of make do you use?

Comment: In StackOverflow, please cut and paste text, using proper formatting, rather than using images.  We can't copy code out of images into answers, and people can't search images for similar problems.

Comment: Go up a directory level (to /usr/src/linux-4.4) and run `make` from there.

Answer (score 0):

After the `make` command, press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to create the `hello.c` file. Then run the `make` command again.